# como recorrer un array con foreach en php

Tags: php, foreach

tengo el siguiente problema con mi foreach ya que estoy consumiendo una función que me regresa un array asociativo:

```
var_dump($respuesta); 

array(7) { ["Codigo"]=> string(2) "28" ["NumeroCaja"]=> string(1) "2" ["Productos"]=> string(102) "[{"total": "1099", "descripcion": "Samsung"}, {"descripcion": "Galaxy A01"}, {"descripcion": "Negro"}]" ["Fecha"]=> string(10) "2022-03-29" ["Total"]=> string(4) "1099" ["Comision3%"]=> string(3) "500" ["Comision5%"]=> string(3) "600" }
```

y lo trato de recorrer en mi foreach de la siguiente manera :

```
foreach ($respuesta as $val) {
echo $val['Codigo'];
}
```

y me arroja este error : **Warning: Illegal string offset 'Codigo'** , entiendo que debe ser porque no está asociando bien o no sabe que $val tiene una asociación "Codigo", entonces como se lo puedo asignar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El array es `$respuesta`. Cuando lo recorres con ese `foreach`, `$val` va tomando el valor de cada elemento del array. Por tanto, `$val` no es un array, y no tiene un elemento `'Codigo'`, de ahí el error.

Creo que no necesitas el `foreach`, lo necesitarías si tuvieras un array de respuestas.

En cualquier caso, conforme a lo que tienes, puedes acceder al elemento `'Codigo'` de respuesta directamente:

```
echo $respuesta['Codigo'];
```

O puedes hacer un `foreach` para mostrar todos los elementos de `$respuesta`:

```
foreach ($respuesta as $val) {
    echo $val . '<br />';
}
```

Por otro lado, si quisieras mostrar los productos, simplemente tienes que acceder al elemento `'Productos'` de tu array `$respuesta`. Pero su contenido es un JSON, así que si lo quieres manejar en PHP tendrás de convertirlo:

```
$productos = json_decode($respuesta['Productos']);
```

`$productos` sí será un array, ahí sí tiene sentido un `foreach` si quisieras hacer algo con los productos uno a uno.

Pero `$respuesta` es un array unidimensional, si fuera multidimensional, osea, un array de respuestas, entonces sí tendría sentido recorrerlo para ir cogiendo los datos de cada respuesta.

**Nota**.- Consulta la documentación de `json_decode` si no has usado nunca esa función, para entender bien lo que te devuelve. En el ejemplo que te he puesto, será un array de objetos. Pero si le pasas un segundo parámetro `true` será un array de arrays.

Comment: si en este caso no es muy necesario el foreach, pero si cambio las variables me regresa un array con mas respuestas (mas códigos, mas productos) , como podría recórrelo si solo necesito mostrar solo los códigos o los productos del array?

Comment: Sigues sin necesitas el `foreach`, simplente accede a cada elemento del array directamente. En el caso de `'Productos'`, como lo que contiene es un JSON, tendrás que decodificarlo. He ampliado mi respuesta para que lo veas.